# Connecting to PostgreSQL gives "could not connect to server" error

Tags: database, postgresql

I have three versions of postgres installed 8.4,9.1 and 9.2 on ubuntu Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (Precise Pangolin). Version 8.4 is running on port 5433, 9.1 on port 5432 and 9.2 on port 5434

when i run `postgres status` i get this

```
8.4/main (port 5433): down
9.1/main (port 5432): down
9.2/main (port 5434): online
```

When i try to connect to version 9.2 using `psql -U postgres template1` i get the following error

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

What can i do to get this working? Hoping to be hearing from you guys.

Comment: Off-topic. This is not a programming question. See: http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well, ***is*** the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?  If not, specify the hostname or IP address in the connect string.

Comment: @OldPro, Thanks for your clue. Your clue was that less missng piece which i needed to get it working. I have published what i did to get it working below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Old Pro. Thanks for your clue. The solution if actually very simple.

After poking around i finally got it working. Since i have three database versions sitting on the same box but running from three different ports all i need do when trying to connect to each database is to explicitly specify the port to which database i want to connect to. PostgreSQL default port is 5432 so when connecting to my version 9.1 i don't have to specify the port but i have to specify the port number when connecting to version 8.1 and 9.2.

I did this to get it working.

**VERSION 8.1 RUNNING ON PORT 5433**

```
psql -p 5433 -U postgres template1
```

**VERSION 9.1 RUNNING ON PORT 5432**

```
psql -p 5432 -U postgres template1
```

**OR**

```
psql -U postgres template1
```

**VERSION 9.2 RUNNING ON PORT 5434**

```
psql -p 5434 -U postgres template1
```