# psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory when trying to run psql command

Tags: database, postgresql-9.1

I'm getting this error when ever I try to run the psql command as the user postgres.

psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I tried specifying the port like what they had on this post here [Connecting to PostgreSQL gives "could not connect to server" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631835/connecting-to-postgresql-gives-could-not-connect-to-server-error) but I'm still getting the same error. The weird thing is that when I try reinstalling psql it works fine, but every time I turn off my computer and turn it back on I end up getting the same error.

Comment: Based on the last sentence, your actual problem would be that postgresql doesn't start at boot time on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you reinstall the postgresql-9.6.3 ?

You need to uninstall postgresql completely

`sudo apt --purge autoremove postgresql*`

`sudo apt install postgresql-9.6`

ubuntu16.04